# Inelastic collision only moving object to the right

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics, trigonometry

My Rocket is hitting this Inertia object, as defined in `handleCollision`. I'm passing in a rocket which has a `.r` value for its theta and `.power` for its magnitude.

I'm wanting to update my `.rotation` & `.magnitude` according to an inelastic collision as defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision#Formula)

When colliding from the left, my Inertia moves to the right.

But when colliding from the right it errors and moves exactly 180 degrees off. So if the rocket is up and right at a 45 degree angle from the inertia object, the object will move up and right at a 45 degree angle.

What am I missing here? I thought it might be an issue with the atan function so I converted by the y component & x component of the vector to radians first, same issue.

```
handleCollision(rocket) {
    var angle = rocket.r * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var rr = this.rotation * Math.PI / 180;

    var rocketVector = {'x' : r.power * Math.cos(angle), 'y' : r.power * Math.sin(angle)};
    var inertiaVector = {'x' : this.magnitude * Math.cos(rr), 'y' : this.magnitude * Math.sin(rr)};

    var rMass = 10;
    var shipMass = 10;

    var x = (rMass * rocketVector.x) + (shipMass * inertiaVector.x);
    var y = (rMass * rocketVector.y) + (shipMass * inertiaVector.y);
    var xDividedByMass = x / (rMass + shipMass);
    var yDividedByMass = y / (rMass + shipMass);

    var yRadians = (yDividedByMass * Math.PI / 180);
    var xRadians = (xDividedByMass * Math.PI / 180);
    var theta = Math.atan( yRadians / xRadians);

    theta = theta * 180 / Math.PI;
    console.log(theta);

    var hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((xDividedByMass * xDividedByMass) + (yDividedByMass * yDividedByMass));
    this.magnitude = hypotenuse;
    this.rotation = theta;
    if (this.rotation < 0) {
        this.rotation += 360;
    } else if (this.rotation > 360) {
        this.rotation -= 360;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not an issue with the radians in the arctan. When you do y/x the pi/180's cancel out anyway. Besides, these are velocity components, not angles.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to follow http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-a-vectors-magnitude-and-direction.html

Comment: Oh, your answer is there. You wanted to add 180 to your vector, not 360. Arctan has a restricted range, and tangent has a period of 180, so you need to use logic to determine the angle based on the range you know it needs to be in.

Comment: this.rotation will not be >360. It will be between -90 and 90.

Comment: You might want to bulletproof this a little in case x is 0, which I think it could be, and bypass the arctan and just set theta to pi/2 (which you may later adjust to a this.rotation of 270 at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If xDividedbyMass>0, you are great because you are quadrant I or IV where arctangent kicks out its values. If you do not like the negative angle, okay add 360 like you did.
But if x<0 and y>0, you will get a negative angle and want to add 180 to get to Q II (tangent has a period of 180). And if x<0, and y<0, you are in QIII and again arctan gives you something in Q1 to which you must add 180.
The logic will look something like this.

```
if ((x > 0) && (y<0)) {
    this.rotation += 360;
} else if (x<0) {
    this.rotation += 180;
}
```